# My Avocado losing leaves

Tags: plant-care

I have an Avocado tree that is about two years old and is about 3 feet tall. Some of the lower leaves are drying up and falling off. I have it in a self watering pot and just moved it under grow lights thinking maybe it might not be getting enough sunlight. I fertilize it once a month.

Comment: A picture could help a lot.     I do wonder if a self watering pot is ideal for avocado.

Comment: We need more details and a picture to give you a good answer, please edit your question and add them